# ios Setting the RoundCorner does not work after override drawRect,but normal UIView is ok

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, drawrect

I wrote an example about Wave Animation.The animation is ok,but I don't understand why the custom UIView needs to add "**self.layer.masksToBounds = YES**" to have the round Corner.

1. This is a custom UIView. I have rewritten its drawRect. If i don't set "*masksToBounds*" to YES, the round corner disappear.

   ```
   - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
       self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
       if (self) {
           self.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 300);
           self.layer.cornerRadius = 150;
           self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
           self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
           self.layer.borderWidth = 2;
           //        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;  //if write this line,the round corner appear
           self.x_move = 0;
           self.y_move = 300;
       }
       return self;
   }

   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

       CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
       CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

       CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
       CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
       CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);

       for(float i=0; i<=300; i++){
           float x=i;
           float y = 5 * sin( 0.05 * x+ self.x_move) + self.y_move;
           CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, x, y);
       }

       CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 300, 0);
       CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0);
       CGContextAddPath(context, path);
       CGContextFillPath(context);
       CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
       CGPathRelease(path);
   }

   - (void)startAnimation {
       if (self.waveTimer == nil) {
           self.waveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(refresh) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
       }
   }

   - (void)refresh {
       self.x_move += 0.3;
       self.y_move -= 0.2;
       if(self.y_move - 100 < 0.00001){
           [self.waveTimer invalidate];
       }else{
           [self setNeedsDisplay];
       }
   }
   ```

ViewController:

```
self.wave = [[waveAnimation alloc] init];
[self.wave startAnimation];
[self.view addSubview:self.wave];
```

2. This is a normal UIView. Its "*masksToBunds*" is NO, but its round corner shows normal. Compared with the examples above, why one should add, one does not need.

   ```
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 100, 100)];
   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   view.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
   view.layer.borderWidth = 2;
   view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
   [self.view addSubview:view];
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is from your override of `drawRect:(CGRect)frame`.

You are attempting to set the corner radius of the layer that is **not** the element you assigned the fill color to. The reason setting `masksToBounds` achieves the desired rounded corner is because here you are telling the view to mask all of it's *layers* to the bounds from your frame.

In your second example with the `UIView` the corner radius appears as expected because you have not adjusted it's layers.

I suggest either adopting setting `masksToBounds` or redraw the view's bounds a different way if you **need** `masksToBounds = NO`. Since you have the "squiggle" sin curve and you want rounded corners, perhaps just create a generic rounded rect (one with the desired corner radius) then merge that with the path you have already created with the sin wave.

[Merge multiple CGPaths together to make one path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539397/merge-multiple-cgpaths-together-to-make-one-path)

That link may help you merge your rounded view with your custom view to achieve the desired end result.

Otherwise.. probably best bet to just set this to yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！The key message is that the layer by myself drew in drawRect and self.layer are different layer.I think that creat a new layer when override "drawRect",so setting "self.layer" is not equal to set the layer drew by myself. is this right ?

Comment: In a round-about way I believe yes what you said is correct. Really no harm in your issue it’s merely a “behind the scenes” technicality. Try either editing the layer itself (self.layer) with your desired path or use `masksToBounds`. Hopefully my answer helped you find you solution! If u feel it did please accept

Comment: apple document -- cornerRadius  " it applies only to the background color and border of the layer. However, setting the masksToBounds property to YES causes the content to be clipped to the rounded corners", I did not understand before,I think that  overriding the "drawRect" mean that I am adjusting the content of layer. so,the cornerRadius does not work ,because the it applies only to the background color and border of the layer.

Comment: Correct. Like I said there is no harm using the mask property just good for you to understand *why*. Things like this are always annoying until figured out